# WebStorm endless code analyzing with useEffect in the component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webstorm

When using the `useEffect` hook in a component, the code analyzer immediately freezes and the code inspection no longer works no matter what you type. If I comment or remove `useEffect`, code analysis starts working again. Haven't noticed this problem with other hooks. ESLint disabled.

WebStorm `2022.2.2`
React `18.2.0`
TypeScript `4.8.4`

[image: Example]

Comment: can't reproduce with similar code using the same IDE and React versions. Does caches invalidation help? Also, could you check if you can repeat the issue in a new React project?

Comment: @lena I didn't know about caches invalidation feature, that fixed the problem. Thanks a lot!